# Good sources for pre-painted minis?

Tags: miniatures

Does anyone know some good places to look for pre-painted minis besides the WOTC and Reaper lines?  I'm interested in either factory-painted or hand-painted.

Comment: This question is no longer considered valid for this site.  See the [FAQ].

Comment: How could this question be fixed? Finding pre-painted minis is a challenge for anyone in the hobby.

Comment: Agree - needs to not turn into a list question or be too localized are the challenges.

Answer (score 5):

em4 do some pre-painted minatures. Here's a few examples.

[image] [image]

Available in the USA from [Crystal Caste](http://crystalcaste.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=CC&Category_Code=EM) or [direct from em4](http://www.em4miniatures.com/acatalog/Pre-painted_Miniatures.html) in the UK.

Comment: Nice.  Kind of a classic look, too, which I definitely like.

Comment: Very nice. Can I order in the US?

Comment: http://www.crystalcaste.com do em4 stuff in the states.

Answer (score 3):

MageKnight figures can usually be found on eBay fairly cheap. The bases are a bit too large, but can easily be replaced with wood, cardboard, or scrap plastic.

Answer (score 2):

Hasbro's Heroscape includes pre-painted miniatures with many that would work very well with D&D. From the first 2 sets I have Vikings, Samurai, and an Elf as well as various other Fantasy and Sci-Fi type figures. You can get booster packs with Orcs, Romans, and other things as well.

Comment: But the bases don't it well on a standard battle mat. My son has a ton of heroscape and we use a lot of the figures but there are sometimes sizing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Rackham has the really nice confrontation line, but the minis are bit larger than wotcs and reapers. Noticeably.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this kickstarter for pre-painted plastic minis http://kck.st/Ym11z6

It's a small company that has done a few sets found here http://www.dungeoncrawler.com/dcm/

Comment: I normally like the Kickstarters but this one doesn't look like a very good deal.  Sad b/c if there were any good ones i would back them..I wish that I could have gotten in on the Reapers Kickstarter it was Very Impressive